# Difference between Logan's Instance theory and Exemplar-Based Random Walk (EBRW) theory

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory, experimental-psychology, attention, mathematical-psychology

I'm trying to find a clear explanation of the difference between Logan's instance theory [(Logan, 2002)](http://www.psy.vanderbilt.edu/faculty/logan/Logan_2002_PR.pdf) and the Exemplar-Based Random Walk theory [(Nosofsky & Palmari, 1997)](http://www.cogs.indiana.edu/nosofsky/pubs/1997_rmn-tjp_pr_an.pdf). Am I mistaken that they are two separate ways of dealing with the question of time and speed of categorization and the Generalized Context Model [(Nosofsky, 1986)](http://www.cogs.indiana.edu/nosofsky/pubs/1986_rmn_jep-g_attention.pdf)? If anyone knows the details of this, I'd be seriously grateful for some help as I am studying abroad in a second language and am finding this topic difficult.